# Como cambiar la configuración regional de MS SqlServer en docker

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, mssql

no soy capaz de cambiar el dateformat y lcid por defecto de la imagen de microsoft:
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

me gustaría poder configurar el contenedor de sql server en es_ES, lcid 1034 y el dateformat en dmy

Tengo un contenedor levantado en la maquina host con ubuntu 20.04 con los siguientes locales

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

el contenedor se levanta desde un docker-compose.yml con la siguiente configuración:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: sqlserver-dev-linux
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
      MSSQL_LCID: "1034"
    volumes:
        - './drive:/var/opt/mssql'
        - './media:/media'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy `
```

y cuando voy a comprobar la configuración me devuelve:

```
Set Option                                                                        Value
----------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------
textsize                                                                           4096
language                                                                     us_english
dateformat                                                                          mdy
datefirst                                                                             7
lock_timeout                                                                         -1
ansi_null_dflt_on                                                                   SET
ansi_warnings                                                                       SET
ansi_padding                                                                        SET
ansi_nulls                                                                          SET
concat_null_yields_null                                                             SET
isolation level                                                          read committed
```

Cualquier ayuda bienvenida, gracias, un saludo.